# How to read array list elements five by five in java

Tags: java, arraylist

The following java code is used to add elements to an `ArrayList` using another `ArrayList` and after that elements of the second `ArrayList` will be used to do above topic . After read the second `ArrayList`, read elements of the `ArrayList` will be removed.

```
Bean bean = new Bean();

String mailAddresses = bean.getMailAddresses();

List<String> emailList = new ArrayList<>(); //1st ArrayList

List<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>(); //2nd ArrayList

String[] split = mailAddresses.split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    String trim = split[i].trim();
    emailList.add(trim);
    System.out.println("Email List - " + emailList.get(i));    
}

if (emailList.isEmpty() == false) {
   for (int i = 0; i < emailList.size(); i++) {
        subList.add(emailList.get(i));
        System.out.println("Sub List - " + subList.get(i));
        System.out.println("Balance - " + subList.size() % 5); 

        if (subList.size() % 5 == 0){           
                break;
        }                
   }
}
// After processed some methods 
emailList.remove(subList.get(j));    

subList.clear();
```

This doesn't work for my actual expected. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `List` `subList` can be used to get the sub `arraylist` in a range.

```
List<String> sublist = emailList.subList(1, 5);
```

Modify this feature to read 5 record by 5 record using a loop

```
List<String> sublist = emailList.subList(i, i + 5);
```

**Sample Code**

```
int sublength = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i = i + sublength) {
    List<String> sublist = list.subList(i, i + Math.min(sublength, list.size() - i));
}
```

Comment: How can I do this ? I have no idea about this .

Comment: Thank you , I will try on this .